# Control cannot be edited

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a sale form with a subform , however i cannot choose data from my combo box.I get the following

`Control cannot be edited , it is bound to autonumber field Item_ID`

Below is the SQL

```
SELECT [tblStockItem].[Stock_ID], [tblStockItem].[Item_ID] FROM tblStockItem ORDER BY [Item_ID];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the purpose of the combo box is to select data, not change stored values.  In that case, make it an unbound control --- meaning leave its Control Source property empty.

Then you can do your data selection based on the combo's value without Access complaining about changes to that autonumber field.

Comment: it solve the issue.However the Item_ID is what links the subform and main form.When i select an `Item_ID`in combo from main form  , the details corresponding to that Item_ID in subform do not change

Comment: Use the combo box in the subform control's *Link Master Fields* property, and leave *Item_ID* in the *Link Child Fields* property.

Comment: There is no combo in the subform , i created one in the main form to change fields in subform(i.e depend on item id).Item id exist both in main form and subform.`Item_ID` is hidden in subform

Comment: Link the main form's combo to the subform's *Item_ID* field.  It doesn't matter whether or not the subform *Item_ID* is hidden.

Comment: can you show me how to do that , i have been trying to do this for hours now.

Comment: Open the subform control's property sheet.  Find the *Link Master Fields* property on the Data tab of that property sheet.  Type in the name of your combo box as the value of that property.  What happens now?

Comment: Thanks a ton ...i was struggling with this for hours, wish i could give more upvotes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83069/discussion-between-user2650277-and-hansup).